# Throwing exception with custom error message in camel

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm trying to throw a custom exception with custom error message in camel. I can do this by setting values to a already defined bean as follows:

```
<CamelContext>
  <route>
    <from uri="timer:myTimer"/>
    <bean ref="myException" method="setErrorCode(errorCode)"/>
    <bean ref="myException" method="setErrorMessage(errorMessage)"/>
    <throwException ref="myException"/>
  </route>
</CamelContext>
```

This approach is working fine. But the problem with this approach is, there will be only one instance of `MyException` and it will cause a kind of race condition when there are multiple concurrent consumers.

Because of this problem, I want to create a new excpetion instance each time. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to create an exception instance inside camel route, set values to it and then throw.

I have read that, beginning from **camel 2.17** there is one additional attribute `message` to set error message. For me, there is constraints that forces me to stick with **camel 2.15**.

So, what would be the proper way to create a custom exception in camel with error code and error message?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you can set a prototype scope to the `myException` bean, so the new exception instance would be created each time.

Comment: Why don't you add a OnException handler for all exceptions there set the exception, or route it to some error handler route which handles the error message?

Comment: @Enigo. After setting scope as prototype, it is giving new object for each reference. As a result, value is being for a bean and exception is thrown with a new bean.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti Actually, there is on global exception handler. But I want to throw some custom exception to indicate the place from where exception is thrown.

Comment: The place where the exception is thrown is included in a exchange property or header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call a bean method that creates and throws a new exception

```
public void blowUp(...) {
   throw new MyException(...);
}
```

Comment: That will work. But is it a good practice to call a method just to throw an exception?

Comment: Yeah or set an exception on the exchange if you pass in Exchange as parameter

Answer (score 0):

and what about Camel throwException?
define exception:

```
<spring:bean id="exception-unimplemented-operation"
    class="java.lang.Exception">
    <spring:constructor-arg name="message"
        value="Unimplemented Operation." />
</spring:bean>
```

...
 and in route
...

```
<cml:otherwise>
    <cml:throwException ref="exception-unimplemented-operation" />
</cml:otherwise>
```

Comment: I don't see, how it is different from the scenario mentioned the question. The question was creating a new exception bean with a custom message. In this answer, there is only one exception object and it is being used for all requests.